# Set current PC date and Time as Default in RadDatePicker

Tags: c#, asp.net

In telerik:RadDatePicker the Date is By default Current Date but time is by default 12:00:00 AM, 06-11-14 12:00 AM. I want to set current PC date and Time  as Default in   RadDatePicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Page_Load of your code-behind:

```
myDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm using the following markup:

```
<telerik:raddatepicker 
         id="rdpValueDate" 
         runat="server"
         mindate="<%# DateTime.Now.Date %>" 
         maxdate="01/01/3000">
</telerik:raddatepicker>
```

Comment: doesn't this result in the user not being able to select dates earlier than your mindate?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which was how to set default date, not how to set min/max date.